# How do I update the scope/ng-model when a third party component modifies the textbox value?

Tags: angularjs, color-picker, angularjs-scope

I want to make an editor with using color picker.

Here is a simplified sample. 
http://jsfiddle.net/xcUev/8/

I'm treating the color as the attribute of angular scope object. 
I made it choosable by using color picker

```
 http://www.html5.jp/library/cpick.html
```

but after choosing the color, It wouldn't affect as the scope.

Do you have any ideas for making it works like how to affect to scope this input state intentionally.

Please help me...

Comment: I also have to say that if you modify the input text directly, it would work.

Comment: Checkout $scope.$apply(), which force a digest update when values are changed outside of angular

Answer (score 2):

I tried bind()ing a `change` event, but it never fired (probably because the color picker stops propagation of the event).  So I next tried bind()ing a `focus` event, and that seems to work (I noticed the textbox lost focus, then got it back again when the canvas was hiding).

HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="data.color" class="html5jp-cpick" cpick>
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('cpick', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            element.bind('focus', function() {
                ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(element.val());
                scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    }
})
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/AQX4H/)